# Is it possible to mirror a network port to evade blocked ports?

Tags: linux, networking, samba

I run a samba server on my dedicated linux machine, but my ISP blocks port 445.

I just changed the host port to 5601, which works good for me, as I'm mounting it via fstab on linux.

However I also want it to work for windows users, and no matter what I tried, windows doesn't like different ports.

Is there a way to "mirror" port 445 to 5601 so both connect to the samba server?

Comment: CIFS isn’t meant to be used over WAN. I urgently suggest you use something else.

Comment: You could leave it as that host port, and port forward at the router. Or better yet, set up a local VPN and use that for external access.

Comment: @DanielB what other software would you suggest? I need it to act as a network drive, have password authorization and work natively on windows.

Comment: You could use WebDAV, but it’s crappy. Your requirements unfortunately cannot be met with Windows and proper procedure.

Comment: @DanielB Is CIFS really that bad? I've used it for a while without issues, is it insecure or anything?

Comment: @JacobPedersen Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify iptables to do port forwarding. Something similar to:

```
# this redirects incoming packets from 5601 to 445
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5601 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 445

# this redirects output packets from localhost to 445 so it works from localhost
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 5601 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 445
```

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost